# progress bar, overlapping of elements and z-index: how can I make it work?

Tags: css, z-index

I have here a progress bar containing three html elements : a yellow block, a red block, and a text block,used as label for the progression.

**demo** : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEgJmL

```
<p class="pinim-pc-bar incomplete"><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill" style="width:80%"><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill-color pinim-pc-bar-fill-yellow"></span><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill-color pinim-pc-bar-fill-red" style="opacity:0.2"></span><span class="pinim-pc-bar-text">8/10<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></p>
```

The red & yellow blocks are surimposed so they mix to a color that represent the percentage of progression (the red bar has a certain opacity set).

BUT my text element do not displays and I don't understand why...

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a negative `z-index` to the bars and `z-index:0` to their container to keep them inside the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and make the text above.

```css
.pinim-pc-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.4);
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color.pinim-pc-bar-fill-yellow {
  background-color: #FFE000;
}
.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color.pinim-pc-bar-fill-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-text i.fa {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
.pinim-pc-bar.color-light .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  color: white;
}
.pinim-pc-bar.empty .pinim-pc-bar-fill {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.pinim-pc-bar.empty .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color {
  display: none;
}
.pinim-pc-bar.empty .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.pinim-pc-bar.incomplete .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p class="pinim-pc-bar incomplete"><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill" style="width:80%"><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill-color pinim-pc-bar-fill-yellow"></span><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill-color pinim-pc-bar-fill-red" style="opacity:0.2"></span><span class="pinim-pc-bar-text">8/10<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></p>

<p>Hi!  This progress bar (colored part) contains three html elements : a yellow block (<em>.pinim-pc-bar-fill-yellow</em>), a red block (<em>.pinim-pc-bar-fill-red</em>), and a text block (<em>.pinim-pc-bar-text</em>),used as label for the progression.</p>

<p>
  The red & yellow blocks are surimposed so they mix to a color that represent the percentage of progression (the red bar has a certain opacity set).
</p>

<p>BUT Why is my text element not displayed ?  Thanks !</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have documented the CSS changes for `.pinim-pc-bar-text`. When elements are positioned absolute they're taken out of the document flow. The same then needs to happen for the text.

```css
.pinim-pc-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.4);
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
}

.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color.pinim-pc-bar-fill-yellow {
  background-color: #ffe000;
}

.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color.pinim-pc-bar-fill-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  /* text-align: center; DOES NOT WORK */
  /* ADDED */  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* END ADDED */
}

.pinim-pc-bar .pinim-pc-bar-fill .pinim-pc-bar-text i.fa {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.pinim-pc-bar.color-light .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  color: white;
}

.pinim-pc-bar.empty .pinim-pc-bar-fill {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.pinim-pc-bar.empty .pinim-pc-bar-fill-color {
  display: none;
}

.pinim-pc-bar.empty .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.pinim-pc-bar.incomplete .pinim-pc-bar-text {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="pinim-pc-bar incomplete"><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill" style="width:80%"><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill-color pinim-pc-bar-fill-yellow"></span><span class="pinim-pc-bar-fill-color pinim-pc-bar-fill-red" style="opacity:0.2"></span><span class="pinim-pc-bar-text">8/10<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code:

```
.pinim-pc-bar.incomplete .pinim-pc-bar-text{position: relative;}
```